# Java Spring&Hibernate: Photos in Blog Posts

Tags: java, mysql, spring, image, hibernate

I've created a very simple blog using Spring Boot, MVC, and Hibernate.  My database is mysql.  Right now the user can only create text posts.  I want the user to simply be able to copy paste an image into his post.  Any ideas as to how I can handle that?

Comment: what is your frontend?

Comment: I am using Thymeleaf for my front end.  But I'm so early into this project I could easily switch to something else if that would make this aspect easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide where you want to store the images. You could store them in the database, or on your server's file system, or in a service like Amazon S3.

My preference would be to store them in S3, because if they are in the database they will make your database very big, which impacts the time it takes to back it up and might impact performance too. If you store the images in S3 you can just create a varchar column in your database to store the path to the file in S3.